# Javascript/JSON- Parsing multiple JSON objects stored in external file

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON file that contains these objects-

```
{"boys": [
        {"firstName": "George", "lastName": "Kristoferson", "email": "george@gmail.com", "sex": "male"},
        {"firstName": "Bill", "lastName": "Madison", "email": "bill@gmail.com", "sex": "male"},

    ],
"girls": [
        {"firstName": "Anna", "lastName": "Calixtus", "email": "anna@gmail.com", "sex": "female"},
        {"firstName": "Marie", "lastName": "Curie", "email": "marie@gmail.com", "sex": "female},
    ]

}
```

I wrote this line to get the key-

```
var people = require("./people.json");
```

However, this only stores "boys" into the variable "people".
How can I store "girls" from the JSON to a variable as well?

Comment: Your `girls` have `"sex": "male"`. Also, cannot reproduce https://codesandbox.io/s/l9rxyyx8wl

Comment: Sorry, I just copy pasted the boys JSON payload and edited that, forget to change the gender

Comment: *"However, this only stores "boys" into the variable "people"."* It certainly does not.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1 :** Use [myjson.com](http://myjson.com/) to get json link of your JSON data.

[image]

**Generated JSON URL :** https://api.myjson.com/bins/l4rfa

**Step 2 :** Fetch the data from the URL using a JQuery [.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) function :

```js
var url = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/l4rfa";

$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    
    var boys = data.boys;
    var girls = data.girls;
    
    console.log("Boys", boys);
    console.log("Girls", girls);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

a) your JSON is invalid, double quotes are missing for the last line

b) did you forgot

```
module.exports = 
    // your JSON
```